# Jetty truststore authentication with SSL client-auth

Tags: ssl, clojure, jetty, truststore

I'm trying to make a web-app with using client keys for client authentication. I think I've figured out the whole truststore problem so I can get the client actually authenticated. However I don't want to require client auth. I just want to test for it and enable features if it's enabled.

I can use .wantClientAuth which will request it, but allow connection if it doesn't exist. But I can't find any property to find out if the request has been authenticated.

This should exist, otherwise what is the purpose of wantClientAuth. How do I use it?

Comment: Neither of these two methods worked. I'm not still actively working on the problem because I was able to find a workaround that involves sending client authorized communication over a separate channel. And I may keep using that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the setup running here, to test it right now, but shouldn't
`request.getUserPrincipal()`
and
`request.getAuthType()` give you what you want.

See http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

*(That assumes you have access to the servlet request in the context in which you're working)*

Comment: I do have the serverlet request. The problem is that both of these are returning nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the servlet API use Tim's method. Here are some other ideas depending your calling context..

After the handshake completes you could call getCertChain on the SSLSession. If it's null then the client didn't authenticate with a client cert.

See the customize method here:

http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/mortbay/jetty/security/SslSocketConnector.java.html

Alternatively you could call getLocalPrincipal or getLocalCertificates on the HttpsURLConnection. If they're null then there is no client cert.